# Why do I need .template in this case

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
struct Obj
{
    template<typename U>
    void m(){};
};

template<typename T>
void func()
{
    Obj<T> v;    // Obj<int> v; is compilable
    v.m<int>();
}
```

This piece of code gives me an error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void f()’:
test.cpp:21:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     v.m<int>();
         ^
test.cpp:21:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
```

However, if I change `Obj<T> v;` into `Obj<int> v;`, it will be compilable.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
v. template m<int>();
```

From the C++ 17 Standard (17.2 Names of template specializations )

> 4 The keyword template is said to appear at the top level in a
>   qualiﬁed-id if it appears outside of a templateargument-list or
>   decltype-speciﬁer. In a qualiﬁed-id of a declarator-id or in a
>   qualiﬁed-id formed by a class-head-name (Clause 12) or enum-head-name
>   (10.2), the keyword template shall not appear at the top level. In a
>   qualiﬁed-id used as the name in a typename-speciﬁer (17.6),
>   elaborated-type-speciﬁer (10.1.7.3), using-declaration (10.3.3), or
>   class-or-decltype (Clause 13), an optional keyword template appearing
>   at the top level is ignored. In these contexts, a < token is always
>   assumed to introduce a template-argument-list. **In all other
>   contexts, when naming a template specialization of a member of an
>   unknown specialization(17.6.2.1), the member template name shall be
>   preﬁxed by the keyword template**

Comment: This is literally the question. It does not explain why .template is needed.